# Parse double without mantissa and exponent separator

Tags: java, double

I have to read double from data files with the following format

```
1.234+5 // = 1.234e+5
1.234-5 // = 1.234e-5
```

I can't change the format and I have to parse millions/billions double from data files(= method should be efficient) .

Can I provide a decimal format or is there a convenient method (available in java jdk) able to parse these doubles ?

```
Double.parseDouble("1.234+5"); // throws NumberFormatException
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("1.234+5");
Scanner.nextDouble(); // throws InputMismatchException
```

**EDIT 1**
Precision for what i call data files : 
Data files are ENDF formatted file which is a really strict format (300 pages manual) and here is an extract of one of these files

```
9.223500+4 2.330248+2          0          0          0          63515 8457
2.22102+16 1.57788+13          0          0          6          03515 8457
4.170051+4 1.312526+3 1.641191+5 1.625818+3 4.413323+6 1.648523+53515 8457
```

I can parse integers with a simple

```
Integer.parseInt()
```

But i can't with double.

Comment: Is the file purely doubles, maybe a csv of doubles?

Comment: Data files are nuclear data files based on Endf format. I will edit question with an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to insert an `e` which is then parseable in the normal way:

```
private static final Pattern INSERT_EXPONENT = Pattern.compile("(.*)([+-].*)");

System.out.println(INSERT_EXPONENT.matcher("1.234+5").replaceFirst("$1e$2"));
System.out.println(INSERT_EXPONENT.matcher("1.234-5").replaceFirst("$1e$2"));
```

This is just quick&dirty and doesn't guard against invalid input.

Comment: Although if you're worried about performance, splitting and recombining the numbers manually is faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it possible to make a pattern only matching special decimal format ? I mean the pattern should match 1.234+5 and not 1.234e5 or 1.234E5?

Comment: The regex already requires one of [`+-`] inside the string. It doesn't care what's around it though.

Comment: Ok thank you, I still need to tune the pattern for leading sign and normal double

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt. I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but this will convert the number into a double format. Hope this will help.

```
    String temp = "1.234+5";
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(temp);
    for(int index = temp.length() - 1; index > 0; index--)
    {
        //this will look for a + or - symbol in your string
        if(temp.charAt(index) == '+' || temp.charAt(index) == '-') {
            str.insert(index, 'e');  //this will insert e before the symbol
            break;
        }
    }
    temp = str.toString();
    System.out.println(temp);
    double a= Double.parseDouble(temp); //convert the string back to a double 
    System.out.println(a); //this is just to test the output

    double b = 1.234e+5;
    System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: Does not handle negative numbers.

Comment: why it does not handle negative numbers?

Comment: Try using `String temp = "-1.234+4"` and you will get a `NumberFormatException` since you're adding an 'e' wherever there is a `+` or `-` symbol. This results in trying to parse `e-1.23e4+5`.

Comment: yeah, you are right, if this is the case, can I just start my index from 1? Do you think it will fix the problem?

Comment: It'd be better to start the loop at the end of the string and stop the loop once a '-' or '+' is found.

Comment: Thank you for answer, the fix for negative numbers works, I'll try it and profile it for my application. I think i will just bring some modifications for normal input. For example 1.23e5 returns 1.23ee5.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need a regex.

```
private void test() {
    String [] test = {"1.234+5", "-1.234-2"};
    for (String s : test) {
        System.out.println(s + " -> " + parse(s));
    }
}

private static final Pattern FindMissingE = Pattern.compile("([+-]{0,1}[0-9.]+)([+-]{0,1}[0-9]+)");
private double parse(String s) {
    Matcher m = FindMissingE.matcher(s);
    if(m.find()) {
        return Double.parseDouble(m.replaceFirst("$1e$2"));
    }
    return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried with your pattern and it works quite well for my "special" double. However I would like to use the same pattern for "normal" double. For example 1.23 will be replaced with 1.2e3

Comment: @JohannMARTINET Then you need to adjust the regex.